# Are questions about GDP/GMP compliance, methodology, batch records etc. on-topic?

Tags: discussion

The idea would be to find out how some of these things are being done in systemic or domain-specific manners, to help make process improvement choices.

Comment: Potentially on-topic. Would you provide some more specific examples so it's easier to say if on or off-topic?